# I Want The Integer Of My Calculator To Change When I Press One Of My JButtons

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, event-listener, actionevent

I have an integer called input which is turned into the String string, I have my oneButton.addActionListener set and public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

if (e.getSource() == oneButton){

input = 1;

}
}

but the number on my calculator stays at 0, any help

**CODE:**

```
//everything is imported

public class Ken implements ActionListener{


static JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
static JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
static JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
static JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
static JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
static JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
static JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
static JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
static JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
static JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
static JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
static JButton timesButton = new JButton("*");
static JButton enterButton = new JButton("=");
static JButton dividButton = new JButton("/");
static JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");
public static int input = 0;    


public Ken(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyCalc");


    String string = ""+input;

    JTextField text = new JTextField(string, 9);
    frame.setSize(476, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(0, 30, 20);
    setLayout(fl);
    Border empty;
    empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(fl);

    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Font f = new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.BOLD, 40);
    Font f2 = new Font("Engravers MT", Font.PLAIN, 40);
    int bHeight = 80;
    int bWidth = 70;
    text.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    text.setFont(f2);
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    text.setEditable(false);


    frame.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    oneButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    oneButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    oneButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    oneButton.setFont(f);
    oneButton.addActionListener(new Evt());
    frame.add(oneButton);

    twoButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    twoButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    twoButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    twoButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(twoButton);

    threeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    threeButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    threeButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    threeButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(threeButton);

    plusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    plusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    plusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    plusButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(plusButton);

    fourButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fourButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fourButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fourButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(fourButton);

    fiveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fiveButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fiveButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fiveButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(fiveButton);

    sixButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sixButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sixButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sixButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(sixButton);

    minusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    minusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    minusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    minusButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(minusButton);

    sevenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sevenButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sevenButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sevenButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(sevenButton);

    eightButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    eightButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    eightButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    eightButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(eightButton);

    nineButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight,bWidth));
    nineButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    nineButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    nineButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(nineButton);

    timesButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    timesButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    timesButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    timesButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(timesButton);


    zeroButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    zeroButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    zeroButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    zeroButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(zeroButton);


    enterButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, bWidth));
    enterButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    enterButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    enterButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(enterButton);

    dividButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    dividButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    dividButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    dividButton.setFont(f);
    frame.add(dividButton);

    frame.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);


}


private static Dimension Dimension(int bHeight, int bWidth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



private static void setLayout(FlowLayout fl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public static void main(String[] args){
 new Ken();
}


private class Evt implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == oneButton){

    }

    }

}


}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already implement the `ActionListener` interface on your main class ' Ken' , so you don't need the `Evt` class in this case.

I'm surprised if that works anyway, because you should get an error as your main class uses `implements ActionListener` but doesn't implement the required function.

So implement the `actionPerformed` in your main class instead of `Evt` and when you attach the a ctionlistener to the button you use `this`.

In your action listener you should do

```
if(e.getSource().equals(oneButton)
```

but that's not the problem anyway.

And in your event handler you must update the gui element that shows the number. Just setting input to 1 isn't enough. So you should make `JTextField text` also a member variable then you can update it's content with this:

```
input = 1;
text.setText(""+input);
```

Also you shouldn't make all the elements static. They are declared as class members anyway.

Comment: thank you, after some debugging using System.out.println() on the actionPerformed I have come to the conclusion that the problom is the input variable is not changing. Any idea?